# Get remote ssl certificate in golang

Tags: ssl, go

I want to receive a TCP connection over TLS. I want to validate client certificate and use it to authenticate the client to my application.
Go has the standard [`crypto/tls`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/) package. It can validate client/server certificates. But I can't find way to get details of the remote (client) certificate, like the common name.

Comment: Wouldn't close--it was messily phrased but "how do I check details of a TLS client certificate" is a perfectly legitimate question.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with `crypto/tls`, but looks like `conn.ConnectionState().PeerCertificates[0]` gets you an [`x509.Certificate`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#Certificate). `conn.VerifyHostname(name)` will just check hostname.

Comment: Yes,thanks. Rewrite it as answer please.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have to call [crypto/tls/Conn.Handshake](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Conn.Handshake).
Then you can read peer certificate:
tlsconn.ConnectionState().PeerCertificates[0].Subject.CommonName

Answer (score 18):

Following code may help you get your answer

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    conf := &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    }

    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "www.google.com:443", conf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error in Dial", err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    certs := conn.ConnectionState().PeerCertificates
    for _, cert := range certs {
        fmt.Printf("Issuer Name: %s\n", cert.Issuer)
        fmt.Printf("Expiry: %s \n", cert.NotAfter.Format("2006-January-02"))
        fmt.Printf("Common Name: %s \n", cert.Issuer.CommonName)

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there also such an easy way to obtain an SSL Cert from a FTP(s) connection, instead of HTTP(s)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

When working with  [crypto/tls](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/) you can query any Conn object for ConnectionState:

```
func (c *Conn) ConnectionState() ConnectionState
```

The ConnectionState struct contains information about the client certificate:

```
type ConnectionState struct {
        PeerCertificates            []*x509.Certificate   // certificate chain presented by remote peer
}
```

The [x509.Certificate](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#Certificate) should be pretty straightforward to work with.

Before the server requests for client authentication, you have to configure the connection with the server certificate, client CA (otherwise you will have to verify the trust chain manually, you really don't want that), and tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert. For example:

```
// Load my SSL key and certificate
cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(settings.MyCertificateFile, settings.MyKeyFile)
checkError(err, "LoadX509KeyPair")

// Load the CA certificate for client certificate validation
capool := x509.NewCertPool()
cacert, err := ioutil.ReadFile(settings.CAKeyFile)
checkError(err, "loadCACert")
capool.AppendCertsFromPEM(cacert)

// Prepare server configuration
config := tls.Config{Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}, ClientCAs: capool, ClientAuth: tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert}
config.NextProtos = []string{"http/1.1"}
config.Rand = rand.Reader
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to do that:

```
func renewCert(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

  if r.TLS != nil && len(r.TLS.PeerCertificates) > 0 {
    cn := strings.ToLower(r.TLS.PeerCertificates[0].Subject.CommonName)
    fmt.Println("CN: %s", cn)
  }

}
```

Comment: your method you can use only in http gandler. My question was about tcp connection.