# How can I fetch a certificate from a URL?

Tags: ssl, go, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to find a function similar to Python's `ssl.get_server_certificate()`, which takes a hostname-port pair and returns a PEM-encoded certificate, but I haven't had any luck.

I've done a fair bit of digging around, but the closest question I've found ([Get remote ssl certificate in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31751764/get-remote-ssl-certificate-in-golang)) did not help, nor did reading through the documentation for the package `crypto/tls`. I'm new to Go, so I may have not understood something in the documentation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/tls"
    "encoding/pem"
)

func GetCertificatesPEM(address string) (string, error) {
    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", address, &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    })
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    var b bytes.Buffer
    for _, cert := range conn.ConnectionState().PeerCertificates {
        err := pem.Encode(&b, &pem.Block{
            Type: "CERTIFICATE",
            Bytes: cert.Raw,
        })
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }
    }
    return b.String(), nil
}
```

Usage:

```
certs, err := GetCertificatesPEM("example.com:443")
```

Comment: Any idea why this is not working for "bitbucket.org:443" or "api.bitbucket.org:443"?

Comment: Sorry it's my problem when printing the result. It works perfectly! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That won’t work if the server checks the client certificate. If the client has no valid certificate, the server breaks TLS connection (the code above does not have a certificate at all.

1. Server <---Client Hello------------- golang code
2. Server ----Server Hello with cert--> golang code
   On this step you already have the server's certificate, but unable to get it in tls.Dial()(connection), because the connection is not established.
3. Server <---Client cert(empty cert)----golang code.
4. Server(if validation is enabled) breaks connection because client certificate is not valid.

Eventually, golang code returns with an error and you do not get a server's certificate, no matter that you already have it on step 2.

Comment: Please consider including some source code to make the answer more complete.

Comment: I wrote about code marked as "solution". That code won’t work if the server checks the client certificate.